# Plural genitive in 1st and 2nd declension - how were mixed genders treated?

Tags: genitive

Genitive plural personal nouns in 1st and 2nd declension: I am wondering how human possessors of mixed gender were treated in ancient Latin. For example, how would the following possessive be translated: 'This is the home *of Mr and Mrs Catullus* (i.e. *of the Catulluses*)? I suspect that the Romans would have used the masculine ending.

Answer (score 9):

As a general rule, groups containing both men and women take the masculine in Latin. For example, a male friend is an *amīcus* (masculine), and a female friend is an *amīca* (feminine). But a group of friends of mixed genders will always be *amīcī*, masculine plural.

However, family names were a bit different in Roman times: they didn't quite have equivalents for "Mr" and "Mrs", and instead of saying "the Juliuses" (*Juliī*) they would generally use "the Julian clan" (*gens Julia*). If you wanted to be really pretentious, you'd use a Greek form: the Cornelius Scipio bloodline (as in Africanus) preferred to be called the *Scīpiadae*. And since clan was determined by birth rather than marriage, the wife of Cornelius wouldn't be in the *gens Cornelia* herself (unless she'd been born into it).

So in your particular case, if you're using ancient Roman names, it might be best to just use two separate genitives: *ecce domus Corneliī Flaviaeque* "behold, the house of Cornelius and Flavia".

Answer (score 4):

In such cases the masculine noun takes precedence (Pinkster 2015, Chapter 13: Agreement).

I found a good example in Pinkster 2015 (example (c) on p. 1285):

> ... propter summam et **doctoris** auctoritatem et **urbis** *quorum* alter te scientia augere potest altera exemplis (Cic. *Off.* 1.1.1)

doctoris - GEN.SG.M., urbis - GEN.SG.F., quorum - GEN.PL.M.